# php and CSV file upload,what if the file has a virus?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

im using this code to upload a CSV file to my server folder and extract the data to be inserted to the database. what if the user accidentally  uploaded a CSV file with virus? does the system/server be enfected with the virus since the system does not execute the file?

```
$name = ($_FILES['fileuploaded']['name']);  
$tmp_name = ($_FILES['fileuploaded']['tmp_name']);
$_SESSION['username']=$username;    
if($name){
   $location = "files/$name";
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);
   $file_handle = fopen("files/".$name, "r");
}
```

Comment: .csv files are just text. unless your system has been configured to treat csv's as executables, it is highly unlikely to be able to infect anything. I would be far more worried about something hacking `['name']` to incldue a path, which your code would blindly use, allowing a malicious user to scribble their file ANYWHERE on their server they want to.

Comment: so that means that even if the CSV file has a virus, the system wont be infected if the user upload it to the system?

Comment: aside of virus, what is the possible threat does CSV file upload that the system can encounter?

Comment: what if someone uploads `remote_shell.php` instead of a .csv? or `nastyvirus.exe`? if that `files` dir is inside your document root (which it appears to be), you're allowing anyone to upload whatever they want, and either serve it up to people and/or run it on your server.

Comment: what if im going to filter and accept only .csv file. read the $tmp_name, extract the content and save to my database?

Comment: then don't move it into a publicly accessible location.

Comment: my goal is to extract the content of the CSV file and save it to the database while securing the system from any threat.

Answer (score 1):

"what if the user accidentally uploaded a CSV file with virus?". I would be more concerned with the question "what if the user INTENTIONALLY uploaded a CSV file with virus". Since you are not checking for the file type, someone could upload a file called bad.php and guess that you might put it in a folder called files and then they could execute it and do all sorts of damage.

Comment: what if i secure the file type, the system reads only .CSV file?

Comment: the system is about uploading of grades, the user convert the excel file and intoo CSV, to avoid encoding of grades i used upload to make it easy for the users. my goal is to provide security to the server from any viruses only.

Comment: That will certainly help. You could also save the file below the document root so it is not accessible from the web server. Or do you need to move it at all. If you don't need to save it just read the temp file.

Comment: i actually dont need to save the file, i just need the content of the file. by making a script to read the CSV and extracting its content, does that prevent the virus from getting in to the system?

Comment: if the system uplaoded the CSV file, does the system execute the CSV file? if the system does not, then the virus wont be infected the system?

Comment: How do you handle someone uploading `nasty.exe.csv`?

Comment: @tadman if the user upload nasty.exe.csv does the system execute it?

Comment: "The system" won't execute it, but one of your users might find a way to do it.